# Troubles with storing username/password

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, svnkit

The problem is that Subclipse 1.8.18 (using SVNKit 1.7.8) with Eclipse 4.3 (from M2 to current M6) does not remember username and password for SVN server after restarting Eclipse.

First I thought that it caused by bug I reported here http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1485, but looks like it is not.

So, the question: is that a bug, or I just do something wrong?
If it is a bug, where I should report it - Eclipse, Subclipse or SVNKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix in that bug report has not been released.  It will be included in the next Subclipse release, which will probably be in a week when SVN 1.7.9 is officially out.

Comment: Yes, I aware that it has not been released, but it's just a minor warning, not the cause of that behavior.

Comment: Subclipse 1.8.19 is out, so you can see if it makes a difference.